# Equivalent of "svn switch" for git-svn?

Tags: git, git-svn

(RHEL 6.2, git 1.7.6.4)

I'm using git-svn to access an SVN repository. I've done the initial checkout with the commands

```
git svn init -s https://svn.myhost.com/svn/myrepo/
git svn fetch
```

I can checkout the latest on the trunk  fine, but I can't find a way to switch to a branch without destroying and recreating the entire local copy of the code and starting from scratch using the desired branch.

What is the appropriate git-svn command to change from https://svn.myhost.com/svn/myrepo/trunk/ to https://svn.myhost.com/svn/myrepo/branches/mybranch ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Subversion branches should be available as normal Git branches. Try

```
git branch
```

to list the available branches. If that doesn't list what you expect, try `git branch -a` to show all of them. To switch to a specific branch, do:

```
git checkout new-feature
```